# How can I avoid making a new conection every five seconds?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, httpconnection

Every five seconds a function :

```
private boolean ping() {
    try {
        URL pingServerUrl = new URL(serverResourceLocator);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) pingServerUrl.openConnection();
        if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            lastPingSuccessful = true;
        }
        System.out.println("pinged");
    }catch(Exception exc) {
       exc.printStackTrace(); 
       return lastPingSuccessful;
    }

    return lastPingSuccessful;

}
```

is called. It is type of ping function. It tries to connect to the servlet on the server and it sends some credentials along with the URL `serverResourceLocator` . The thing that bothers me is that a new connection is opened every 5 seconds.

How can I avoid it ?

Comment: What is your goal? To monitor availability of server?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov to make server cognizant of the client's connectivity to the server. After a certain time-out server removes the client's name and other data from the database

Comment: A new connection every 5 seconds (from a limited number of clients) doesn't sound that bad at all .. any numbers/use-case substantiating this fear?

Comment: @pst there could be around 100 clients at a time.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Run it through a mock stress-test. Then you can worry with justification or move onto something else. (That is "only" 20 very short lived connections/second on average and it might even reveal other issues!) Of course, there might be other ways of performing the intended "heartbeat" more appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

You can't recycle an HTTP connection. HTTP is a stateless protocol. The best you can do is to not close the connection once it is opened and keep it alive and send a heartbeat message from the server down to the client.

Comment: aah...can you please elaborate. _"....nce it is opened and keep it alive and send a heartbeat message from the server down to the client."_

Comment: Although "not close" is not necessarily better (or "best") here .. the internet has had a long time to optimize for numerous short-lived connections. Sure, there is an extra TCP handshake and a little extra HTTP header data: but who cares? :D Plus, new connections avoid having to have a long-running request.

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) for a start.

Comment: Boy, I should really change my username. @pst, I was just trying to refer to a general page about keep-alive. Suhail, what are you trying to accomplish? I'm starting to wonder if you even need http here (you can probably just get away by a TCP connection depending on your goal).

Answer (score 0):

If the use of the function is what I am guessing it to be, i.e. to test the servlet, it is best to leave the connection part in; you get more coverage out of your test script. A connection every 5 seconds is hardly anything. The server would not feel anything.

Else just store the connection as a global variable. And reuse it every time you make a request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any alternative to this. You will have to make http connection to get status of the URL.

Below 2 are lightweight alternatives of **Java**

- Unix curl utility
- Ajax call from your java script

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want to remove client's data after EXPIRY_TIME.

I think one of the two methods can be followed:

1. You can check with some cron job (scheduler) in session modified time (which suggests last access time)
2. For each client request, set access log in flat file system and check with cron job in access log

In any of the case, if last access time > EXPIRY_TIME then remove client's data.

This approach will save round trips and help to reduce traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can release the connection once the job is done.Anyhow java webserver is designed to take multiple request.Even though every 5 seconds request is coming to the server,its not a problem.